# Telnet Issue :Connecting To localhost… Connect failed

Tags: connection, port, telnet

I'm trying to telnet the 13013 port on localhost but I keep getting this error:

```
Could not open connection to the host, on port 13013: Connect failed
```

I turned off my firewall, and even tried the command with Windows Powershell (Admin) and still got the same message.

what could be the problem?

Update:

I tried that on my virtual machine where the connection was established and I could open a connection but when I tried that on my windows, I still had a problem opening the connection.

Comment: Are you sure there's something listening on that port?

Comment: yes. please read the update.